# Dynamically created <td> related function issues

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a date picker that I've created which highlights today on its initial load and then highlights whatever date the user clicks on. This works fine on the initial month, but when moving forward to the next month, the script for highlighting does not work.

```
$('td').on('click',function(){
    $('td').removeClass('selectedDate');
    $(this).addClass('selectedDate');
});
```

Please see the following fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/yuqu6v3v/3/

I tried adding a simple alert to the above function:

```
$('td').on('click',function(){
    alert('I am a table cell');
    $('td').removeClass('selectedDate');
    $(this).addClass('selectedDate');
});
```

as well as a fork of the page ( https://jsfiddle.net/wvrfnwxs/ ) that included:

```
$('#calendar').on('click',function(){
    alert(this.innerHTML);
});
```

to confirm that the selector $('td') should still be valid.

Is there something in `function nextMonth()` or `function Calendar()` when it redraws the next month's days that is causing the selector to become invalid?  Or something else happening that is preventing the desired highlighting?

Thanks for any help provided!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that this code:

```
$('td').on('click',function(){
```

...binds a click handler to any td elements that exist *at that moment*. When you click the next month button you recreate the whole table, so those previous td elements are gone and you don't bind any click handler to the new ones.

The simplest fix is to use a delegated event handler bound to a containing element:

```
$('#calendar').on('click', 'td', function(){
// Note this argument -----^^^^
```

Your `#calendar` element is never replaced, so such a click handler will continue to work. When a click event occurs on that element, jQuery automatically checks whether the original target element matches the selector provided in the second argument to `.on()`. If it does it calls your function, otherwise it does nothing.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/yuqu6v3v/5/

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks for that bit of code, but even more for the explanation.  It brought to question some of my understanding of `.on` and is prompting me to read up.  Thanks!  =)

Comment: Yeah, the `.on()` method behaves in different ways depending on what arguments you pass it.